# Issue with MySql Inner Join > not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am having trouble with this statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    User_ID
FROM
    [WebServiceMGT].[dbo].[WEBSERVICE_USERS] P
INNER JOIN [WebServiceMGT].[dbo].[FEATURE_AUTHORIZATIONS] C ON P.USER_SYSID = C.USER_SYSID  
WHERE
    c.Feature_SysID in ('1','2')
GROUP BY
    c.USER_SYSID
HAVING
    COUNT(c.USER_SYSID) = 2
```

I am getting the error Column 'WebServiceMGT.dbo.WEBSERVICE_USERS.USER_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Anyone have any clue as to why?

Thanks

Comment: Remove DISTINCT, put UserID in the GROUP BY instead of USER_SYSID

Comment: if mysql 5.7 there is an sql_mode by default open [mode_only_full_group_by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) you can consider it the disable but it will not be a proper solution just mentioning it

Comment: Thanks for the comment Mihai! It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple: The `select` clause is executed after the `group by` clause. Since you have a `group by` clause, you will have a modified relation when you reach the `select` clause. This modified relation holds the grouped columns and other columns can only be used through aggregate functions.

Your `distinct` is not needed if you put that `User_ID` column into the `group by` instead of `USER_SYSID`